# Validate if date is before date of current date

Tags: javascript, date

Using this function, I'm getting a 7 days difference; how can I test whether a date is before the current date?

```
function validateDate() {
    pickedDate = Date.parse("05-Jul-2012".replace(/-/g, " "));
    todaysDate = new Date();
    todaysDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    dateDifference = Math.abs(Number(todaysDate) - pickedDate);
    //7 Days=604800000ms
    if (dateDifference > 604800000) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: if user enters date before date of current date then i have to generate alert.

Comment: see today date is 05-Jul-2012 if he picks 04-Jul-2012 or before 04 jul then i have to generate alert

Comment: `todaysDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);` what's that for in your code?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can directly compare both dates as

```
return pickedDate <= todaysDate
```

For exact date comparison considering milliseconds you can use
[getTime() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)

You can parse date as you have done:

```
pickedDatestr = "09-Apr-2010"
var pickedDate = new Date(Date.parse(pickedDatestr.replace(/-/g, " ")))
```

Comment: my picked date is in this format "dd-MMM-yyyy" how i convert todays date in  "dd-MMM-yyyy" format

Comment: if pick todays date then also getting alert see  if (pickedDate > todaysDate)
   {
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
    alert("lapsed date.");
    return false;
   }

Comment: it will check for the miliseconds also. hence alert is displayed.

Comment: No i have to only check for date

Comment: you can try JavaScript getMilliseconds() Method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmilliseconds.asp

Comment: dateDifference = Math.abs(Number(todaysDate) - pickedDate);
                //7 Days=604800000ms
                if (dateDifference > 604800000)
                {
                    return false;
                }

Comment: in my above code getting milliseconds thts y i ask how i try for before date using above code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13460/discussion-between-hemant-metalia-and-john)

Comment: According to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmilliseconds.asp the getMilliseconds() method returns the milliseconds (from 0 to 999) of the specified date and time.
You should use getTime() method https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: yes, for more exact getTime would be exact. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 30):

For date comparison (without time):

```
function isDateBeforeToday(date) {
    return new Date(date.toDateString()) < new Date(new Date().toDateString());
}

isDateBeforeToday(new Date(2016, 11, 16));
```

Test cases:

```
// yesterday
isDateBeforeToday(new Date(2018, 12, 20)); // => true

// today
isDateBeforeToday(new Date(2018, 12, 21)); // => false

// tomorrow
isDateBeforeToday(new Date(2018, 12, 22)); // => false
```

Comment: What if the date being compared against is earlier in the day of the same date? It could in theory return true, if you ran this at 8 PM and the date being compared was at 2 PM.

Comment: @BarryChapman You are completely right about that! This code is limited to comparing integer date values only (as requested by the author). Comparing datetimes would be a different use case, which can be solved with a standard date comparison (dateA > dateB).

Comment: This is working for date comparisons, its really helpful because i was not checking for `datetimes`, so thanks!

Comment: Great answer but could you please improve your examples as these as they are may confuse new developers. The month parameter is actually `monthIndex` (0-11). While using 12 is accepted and does not throw an error, it is interpreted as the following January. It would be better to use 0-11 in your examples.

Answer (score 6):

I came to this question because I was trying to check if my Java.util.Date that I was getting from my back-end was after today's date.

In the end I found a really simple solution - by comparing milliseconds, like this:

```
  isAfterNow(date) {
    return new Date(date).valueOf() > new Date().valueOf();
  }
```

The function `valueOf()` is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf).

Comment: But if the date value is just a few minutes or even a few milliseconds more than the result of new Date().valueOf(,) it will return true, won't it? And if so, it's not exactly after today.

Comment: You are right. I'll rename the funciton to "isAfterNow", which is what it actually does. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
new Date() > new Date('2022-01-24')
```

On my end, I careless about the time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
function checkDate(day, month, year)
{
    var regd = new RegExp("^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})\$");

    var date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    var date = new Date(date);
    var today = new Date();

    var vdob = regd.test(date);

    var err_txt = "" ;

    if(date.getDate() != day || (date.getTime()>today.getTime()))
    {
            err_txt+=("Please select a valid Date.\n")
    }

    return (err_txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will check whether a date occurs before today:

```
function isBeforeToday(){
  var today = new Date((new Date()).toString().substring(0,15));
  return date < today;
}
```

This works by creating a new date object after stripping all time information from its corresponding date string:

`Tue Mar 06 2018 16:33:15 GMT-0500 (EST)` -> `Tue Mar 06 2018` -> `Tue Mar 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.dateString1.getFullYear() <= this.dateString2.getFullYear() )//check the year
  { 
    // console.log("date1+date2"+this.dateString1.getFullYear()+this.dateString2.getFullYear())
    if(this.dateString1.getMonth() <= this.dateString2.getMonth())//check the month
      {
        // console.log("date1+date2"+this.dateString1.getMonth()+this.dateString2.getMonth())
        if(this.dateString1.getDate() < this.dateString2.getDate())//check the date
        this.toastr.error("Project Start Date cannot be Previous Date");
          return;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly compare the 2 dates using '<, '>', etc.

```
function validateDate(date) {
    //get start of day using moment.js
    const now = Moment().startOf('day').toDate();
    if (date < now) {
        return false; //date is before today's date
    } else {
        return true; //date is today or some day forward
}
```